# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked error in Angular when printing contents of array

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component, `EditorComponent` (parent),  that represents a test broken down into a series of steps. Each step is modeled by another component, `TestStepComponent` (child), which has a FormGroup containing a number of FormControl instances. The user may add and remove test steps dynamically.

`TestStepComponent` emits an event when the value of its internal FormGroup is changed. `EditorComponent` subscribes to this event, and when the event is emitted, the controller class will validate each `TestStepComponent` instance. The indices of the invalid instances will be stored in a field on the `EditorComponent` controller.

I would like to display to the user the indices of the invalid test steps. However, when I print the internal `InvalidTestStepIndices` array in the template, I get an error in the console: `NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.` How can I get the list of invalid indices without triggering this error?

EDIT: I put together something that exhibits similar behavior at StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-reactive-forms-kludgey-sketch?file=src/app/app.component.html . I get the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` after I add a step, and it's because the "Preview" button changes from enabled to disabled (if all the steps that were present previous to me adding the new one were valid). So maybe I need a way to correctly add / remove steps?

Comment: Wrap it in a setTimeout..?

Comment: I've seen that pattern in a `ViewChildren` example, but I'm not sure what purpose it serves. Can you explain what wrapping it in a `setTimeout` does?

Comment: It makes change detection skip one cycle for that specific change. You can set the timeout to 0. Mind you, it is still a bit of a hack but sometimes you don’t have much choice..

Comment: I tried that and it did the trick. Post that in an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: What I ended up doing was in `AddItem`, `RemoveItem`, and `ItemChanged` to wrap the call to `doValidCheck()` (which sets the class variable used to determine whether the form is valid or not) in `setTimeout`: `setTimeout(() => doValidCheck())`. That caused the validity check to wait until the new elements had been added to the DOM before executing.